# WSO2 Carbon - Programmatically Apply Security

Tags: security, wso2

I am attempting to write code to programmatically secure a service on a WSO2 Carbon server. I have deconstructed the JSP security code enough to know that it uses the SecurityAdminService to actually execute security operations. I am successfully sending messages to the SecurityAdminService, but get the following error:

```
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:axis2ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <faultcode>axis2ns1:50977</faultcode>
    <faultstring>Access Denied. Please login first.</faultstring>
    <detail/>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

This is not really unexpected, but I cannot figure out any way to pass user credentials in this request. The JSP code doesn't offer much help here, as it does login and credential handling through cookies. Is there a way to handle authorization at the same time as the request? Or do I need to just copy what the JSP pages do and POST to a login URL and copy the session cookie into the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling any of the admin services, you have to first call the AuthenticationAdmin service and get yourself authenticated (against the carbon userstore), as a valid user. You can easily use the AuthenticationAdminStub to call its login method providing your username, password and the hostname/ip of the backend server to get this done. Then you ll be able to successfully proceed with what you've already implemented.

Regards,
Prabath

Comment: Does the API automatically  stores the session cookie after i call AuthenticationAdminStub#login()?

Comment: If you were able to successfully log in, then it is possible for you to retrieve the ServiceContext from the relevant stub and then retrieve the session cookie which is stored in it as a property. For example, the following code snippet would get it for you.

Comment: serviceContext = authenticationAdminStub._getServiceClient().
                getLastOperationContext().getServiceContext();
        sessionCookie = (String) serviceContext.getProperty(HTTPConstants.COOKIE_STRING);

Comment: Once you successfully obtained the session cookie you can use that to authenticate all the other client stubs that are corresponding to the admin services thereby acquiring the capability to invoke their functionalities.

Comment: This is exactly the service I was looking for. Note for others: Still have to carry the JSESSION cookie header around in the service calls after logging in, but [`HttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) handles that well.